# How to compare property in two different objects and operate on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
a= [{
    "id": "567",  
    "username": "foo",  
    "profile_title": "Senior Analyst"
  },
  {         
    "id": "123",   
    "username": "bar",   
    "profile_title": "Program Management"
  }]

b= [{
    "URL": "https://abcd.com",
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://efgh.com",
    "id": "456"
  }]
```

I have two arrays with objects, I need to compare id and if they match, need to copy URL property from b to a.

Comment: How would you like to compare it? Is it like a[0].communityid === b[0].communityid ? Or is it like finding an id from b array that matches an id from a array?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following code.

```
a.map((a_item, a_index) => {
  b.some((b_item, b_index) => {
    if(a_item.communityid === b_item.communityid){
      a[a_index].URL = b[b_index].URL;
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `for` `loop`

```js
var a= [{
    "communityid": "2032",  
    "username": "foo",  
    "profile_title": "Senior Analyst"
  },
  {         
    "communityid": "2085",   
    "username": "bar",   
    "profile_title": "Program Management"
  }];

var b= [{
    "URL": "https://abcd.com",
    "communityid": "2032"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://efgh.com",
    "communityid": "2085"
  }];
 for(i in a){
     for(j in b){
          if(a[i].communityid == b[j].communityid){
             a[i].URL = b[j].URL;
          }
     }
   
 }
 
 console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple understanding and static comparison try this, you can use a recursive method to loop through it once you understood it.

```
let fun = ()=>
 {
   if(a[0].username == b[0].usernmame)
   {
     return "Matched!"
   }
  else{
     return "Bad luck!"
  }
 }
console.log(fun());
```

key element:  a[0].username == b[0].usernmame,a[1].username == b[1].usernmame etc